# What are some good introductory book references on time-varying electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, resource-recommendations

What are some good introductory book references on time-varying electromagnetic fields? I need a refresher on the physics background on this topic. I intend to do research in electric motor-related research.

Answer (score 1):

*Introduction to Electrodynamics* by David Griffiths has been a standard choice for a long time.  You can't go wrong there.  Not the only choice, but a good one.

Comment: It does not have an extensive discussion about time-varying electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Maybe you should refine your question then.  Is the emphasis on introductory or on details of time varying fields?  Those may not go together as much as you seem to want.

Comment: Since I gave the name of a normally considered  narrow subarea of "time-varying EM", of course a general-purpose text without particularly good or extensive discussion about the subarea is not a particularly useful answer or even a viable one. I put the particular subarea of interest in the question for a reason.